# Notify host of changes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application and a C# application hosting a WebBrowser. The ASP.NET application is run through the C# application.

I am in need of notifying the C# application when e.g a button is clicked. The best approach will probably be through Javascript. This doesn't seem complicated as I can expose functions for the javascript window.external, but the only URL my C# application sees is the /Default.aspx. All the javascript functions (window.external.myfunc(..)) has to come from this page.

Any ideas? I'm turning up blank. I'm also a bit unsure on how to call the javascript functions from code-behind. ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock seems to be used a lot, but can this be called several times at one page?

Thanks!

By the way, for the C# client I'm using WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting to a custom object which will take these window.external function calls from Javscript. This works.

Comment: `window.external` and `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting` is the way I'm using, too.

Comment: Yeah, my issue is how to call the window.external from the code-behind. Even from other internal pages, it all has to come from the page in the WebBrowser URL is seeing (which is the default.aspx).

So calling window.external from myOtherPage.aspx will not work, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The part with `ObjectForScripting` and `window.external` will work fine.

And in order to call js functions from your ASP.NET code, you should use `ajax` calls from the js. There are two approaches for that:

1- create a web service and invoke it constantly to check for anything that has happened (i.e polling). this is the simplest way and can be easily implemented, for example using `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax(...);
```

then call your `window.external.func()` from the callback to that ajax call (of course if it's returned the intended value). Note that with this method, you will always have a delay because the client should poll the server.

2- make a connection to the server and keep it open, then send the data from the server when it's ready. For this matter, you can make use of something like `SignalR`. This will solve the issue of delay, but will keep an open connection which in turn brings other issues.

Actually the main factor to decide between these two methods is whether you are okay with a delay. If it's not the problem to wait for an average of 15 seconds, use the first method with a polling time of 30 seconds. If you want it to be real-time, use the second method but be cautious with its own issue like long-running connections, lack of session-state in SignalR and so on.

I just wanted to show you the choices. please tell me if it's unclear in any manner.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested a bit and I can see that window.external works.

My issue at hand for the moment is returning the value from the Javascript to the code-behind (as this sends a parameter which the C# application needs to approve or not). Any suggestions?

Comment: OK. Let's review the whole scenario. You want the code behind send values to the page `AFTER` it is loaded, then call some methods on the `window.external` object, get some values from the user and at last return this acquired values back to the ASP.NET page. correct?